# Vue component not rendering in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, vue.js

I am new to Vue and as of now I am using Vue 1.0. In my laravel app vue components aren't getting loaded. I ain't getting any error in the Vue devtool or the chrome devtool either. Here's my code:

My master.blade.php layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vue</title>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <component is="{{ $vueView }}">
                @yield('content')
            </component>
        </div>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My about_page.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master', ['vueView' => 'AboutView'])

@section('content')
    <h2>About View</h2>
@endsection
```

My home_page.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master', ['vueView' => 'HomeView'])

@section('content')
    <h2>Home View</h2>
@endsection
```

My resources/assets/js/dynamic_components.js

```
// Browserify Entrypoint

import Vue from 'vue';
import HomeView from './components/HomeView.vue';
import AboutView from './components/AboutView.vue';


new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    components: {
        HomeView, AboutView
    }
});
```

My /resources/assets/js/components/AboutView.vue

```
<template>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque placeat, quis maiores sequi inventore, voluptatibus labore hic fugit, autem consequuntur ipsum ex laudantium. Accusamus optio veniam velit, laudantium. Odit, facilis.
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        ready() {
            alert('home view is ready');
        }
    }
</script>
```

My /resources/assets/js/components/HomeView.vue

```
<script>
    export default {
        created() {
            alert('Welcome to the Home Page');
        }
    }
</script>
```

My routes.php

```
Route::get('/home-view', function () {
    return view('home_view');
});

Route::get('/about-view', function () {
    return view('about_view');
});
```

My gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vueify');

elixir(function(mix) { 
    mix.browserify(['main.js', 'dynamic_components.js']);
});
```

All it shows is the `h2` from `home_page.blade.php` and `about_page.blade.php` respectively. Where am I going wrong???

`Sorry for such a long post....`

Answer (score 0):

Done. I reinstalled the project. It is working now.
Sorry for the trouble.